# LongListSelector adjust based on screen width

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I am new to windows phone 8 development and i have a very basic question i believe.

I wish to make my LongListSelector have 100% width and height but all the things i have tried didnt work.

I have tried Auto, * etc but nothing seems to do it.

Here is my code:

```XAML
<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.SetupsPageTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <phone:LongListSelector HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Width="400" Height="400"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                        Name="lstSetups" ItemsSource="{Binding BusRouteSetups}"
                        SelectionChanged="lstSetups_SelectionChanged"
                        LayoutMode="List">
            <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,10,0,10" Background="Coral">
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5"  FontWeight="Bold"  Text="{Binding Details.Title}" />
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="5"  Text="{Binding Details.Description}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        </phone:LongListSelector>

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: You've set the `Width` property of the `LongListSelector` to `400`, it will never be wider than that...

Comment: I have set the width and height so that i can work with it until i find a solution.

Comment: Then please post code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use HorizontalAlignment = Stretch (also Vertical), then Width and Height of LLS will be set to maximum space that is available to that Control:

```
<phone:LongListSelector HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"                  
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                        Name="lstSetups" ItemsSource="{Binding BusRouteSetups}"
                        SelectionChanged="lstSetups_SelectionChanged"
                        LayoutMode="List">
```

Note that it's maximum height will be determined by Grid (parent of Control). While you have set RowDefinition's Height to `*` - it means that it will use all the remaining height of the screen (remaining - some space is used by first row (set to auto) - StackPanel with title).

Answer (score 1):

**HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Width="400" Height="400" VerticalAlignment="Top"**

Just remove this part of your code and then the control should be sretched automatically.